# Chose how many times the bot rolls (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Right now I'm working on a random number generator to be like a virtual dice roller. I have users input a number and the bot randomly chooses a number between 1 and whatever the user inputs. I've been trying to add in a way for users to first say how many times they want it to roll. I'm very confused about how to go about doing this with the code I have already.

A quick run down:
I want the bot to ask after the user sends the max number to roll I want the bot to ask how many times they want to roll it.

code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

function getRandomInt(max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

const prefix = 'roll';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('your bot name is online!');
    client.user.setActivity("Type 'Role Help'", {type: 3}); 
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === ''){
       message.channel.send("What's the **Max** role number you want?");
       message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
        {max: 1, time: 10000}).then(collected => {
            console.log('collected :' + collected.first().content);
            if (isNaN(collected.first().content)){
                return message.channel.send("Please provide a valid number!")};
            
            var n = (getRandomInt(collected.first().content));  
            message.channel.send("You Rolled a " + (n + 1));
            }).catch(() => {
                message.channel.send("*Roll has been cancelled.*");
     
            })} else if(command === 'Help' || 'help' || 'h' || 'H'){

                message.channel.send("**How to use Roll Bot**");
                message.channel.send("*1. Type Roll to begin*");
                message.channel.send("*2. Input a number or type stop to end the roll.*");
                message.channel.send("**Have Fun!**");
        }
});

client.login(process.env.token);
```

Comment: Store an argument in a variable then do a loop to send a message for that variable count

Comment: @Elitezen anyway I can get an example? I think I understand but I just want to make sure